# Xml Parsing using SAX parser in Android application.

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

Can anybody please solve my Issue regarding XML SAX Parsing:

I have a small issue that in my Android application when parsing is done, it goes through the whole response and parse the data.

My issue is that I just want to parse the data from the particular place. So that when I parse the XML Response, parsing should be done from the desired place and then it should not check further even if the "same tag" used to appear elsewhere in the response.

Is there any way to do this? I am stranded in this situation badly and have no clue for what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try using xmlpullparser instead of SAX parser, Android supports xmlpullparser too

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting your Eclipse, or the framework you are using.

Comment: Thanks for giving the Funny answer , but I am stuck somewhere badly and So no smiles on this Joke.....